# error on invalid function: abbrev

Tags: emacs, emacs24

I used to use Emacs in windows, recently I want to try Ubuntu 14.04. I used the same settings, same `init.el`, same packages. but I got an error when start Emacs under Ubuntu.
I am not an elisp programmer, and I hope I can get some help here. I am using Prelude for Emacs 24, but even I run emacs with `-Q`, the same error is still there....

The errors are as follows:

```
Debugger entered--Lisp error: (invalid-function "abbrev")
  "abbrev"("convenience" "matching")
  byte-code("\300\301\302\303\304\305\306\307\310\311\312\"&\207" [define-package "company" "20140731.944" "Modular text completion framework" ((emacs "24.1") (cl-lib "0.5")) :url "http://company-mode.github.io/" :keywords "abbrev" "convenience" "matching"] 11)
  load("/home/zhijia/.emacs.d/elpa/company-20140731.944/company-pkg" nil t)

  package-load-descriptor("/home/zhijia/.emacs.d/elpa" "company-20140731.944")
  package-maybe-load-descriptor("company" "20140731.944" "/home/zhijia/.emacs.d/elpa")
  package-load-all-descriptors()
  package-initialize()

  byte-code("\302\303!\210\302\304!\210\305\306\307\310#\210\311\312\"\313 \207" [prelude-dir package-user-dir require cl package add-to-list package-archives ("melpa" . "http://melpa.milkbox.net/packages/") t expand-file-name "elpa" package-initialize] 4)

  require(prelude-packages)
  eval-buffer(#<buffer  *load*> nil "/home/zhijia/.emacs.d/init.el" nil t)  ; Reading at buffer position 4156
  load-with-code-conversion("/home/zhijia/.emacs.d/init.el" "/home/zhijia/.emacs.d/init.el" nil nil)

  load("/home/zhijia/.emacs.d/init.el" nil nil t)
  load-file("~/.emacs.d/init.el")
  call-interactively(load-file record nil)
  command-execute(load-file record)
  execute-extended-command(nil "load-file")
  call-interactively(execute-extended-command nil nil)
```

Answer (score 2):

It seems you need to remove the ~/emacs.d/elpa/company-XXX and re-install it.

Even if you call it with `-Q`, it still has a startup file that checks the `~/.emacs.d/` directory.

Try first to remove the .elc files before to remove everything.

Answer (score 2):

Delete `~/.emacs.d/elpa`, restart Emacs, and let Prelude install all packages again.

It looks like you've stumbled across incompatibilities between package.el in different Emacs versions.  I'm not sure why, though.  Normally errors like this only occur when upgrading from Emacs 23 to 24, or when upgrading from Emacs 24.3 to the (not yet released) Emacs 24.4.  Neither of these seem to be the case here, though.

You are getting this error with `emacs -Q` as well, because `emacs -Q` still loads all user-installed packages from `~/.emacs.d/elpa`.

Comment: I suspect it's enough to remove only the .elc files and keep the rest.

Comment: @alinsoar I'm not sure.  This error comes from evaluting the `-pkg.el` descriptors, and these are generated by package.el upon installation.